# How can I display MySQL-data in an array as in example?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I want to use a solution shown on StackOverflow [PHP Determine when multiple(n) datetime ranges overlap each other](http://www.example.com/)!
To work with it I query the results from MySQL. As in the solution a user can have multiple date entries.

So far I have an array, but it's not grouped by users (named invitees) who have added their dates.

```php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $arr[$row['invitee']];

        $temp = array($row['start_time'], $row['end_time']);

        $arr[] = $temp;
    }
```

With the following output result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-10-16 00:00:00
            [1] => 2019-10-31 23:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-10-17 12:12:00
            [1] => 2019-10-18 20:40:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-10-12 10:00:00
            [1] => 2019-10-24 20:00:00
        )
...
```

What I expect or want to achieve is an array as shown in the post mentioned above:

```
$availability = [
    [
        ["2016-04-30 12:00", "2016-05-01 03:00"]
    ],
    [
        ["2016-04-30 03:00", "2016-05-01 03:00"]
    ],
    [
        ["2016-04-30 03:00", "2016-04-30 13:31"],
        ["2016-04-30 15:26", "2016-05-01 03:00"]
    ]
];
```

to use the solution from the post.
But how can I achieve it that my MySQL-data can be displayed like this?

Comment: did you tried the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to modify your array inside `while` as like:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array(array($row['start_time'], $row['end_time']));
    $arr[$row['invitee']] = $temp; 
}
```

add one another array here `array(array($row['start_time'], $row['end_time']))`

**Edit:**

```
<?php
$finalArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $finalArray[$row['invitee']][] = array($row['start_time'], $row['end_time']);
}
?>
```

**Explanation:**

With this code you can get multiple invitation against each users.

Comment: I am trying. Seems not to work, but I assume it could also be a problem on my side. There are four different invitees with multiple entries in the table. So I need to arrange them to get bundled (like the third entry in the expected result).

Comment: no idea about this, but if you have multiple users then you cant track you must need to use userid in index i thnk @nucky

Comment: Yep, it seems so. Maybe I should rather find another solution than the one proposed in the topic.

Comment: sure @nucky: then you can modify your question or close

Comment: I will keep it open for a day in case that I find a solution.

Comment: @nucky: but u need to modify your question aswell,

Comment: @nucky: i have updated my answer using `$arr[$row['invitee']]`

Comment: Thanks. Looks already better. Close to what I am looking for. Is it somehow possible to put a while-loop into a while-loop for mysql-fetching? This would be the part necessary to get all the entered dates. At the moment it picks only one per user.

Answer (score 0):

See if is working :

```
    $res = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$res[ ]= [$row['start_time'], $row['end_time']];
 }
```